# How can I modify this regex to require a specific numeric range and also allow an empty string?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
^([1-9]){3,5}[1-8]$
```

it works to restrict strings within a certain range, but now I need to change that so that it'll also allow an empty string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(([1-9]){3,5}[1-8])?$
```

Use `(?:` if you care about the captured groups, if you don't, you can remove the brackets around `[1-9]`. Brackets around the whole sequence must be kept, though, so the `?` quantifier still applies correctly (preceding group zero or one times). So the slightly shorter (maybe more correct) version would be:

```
^(?:\d{3,5}[1-8])?$
```

This will return exactly one match, which is the input string as a whole.

Comment: Thanks Simon - not sure what you mean about "captured groups" though?

Comment: Best explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^(|([1-9]){3,5}[1-8])$
```